# Updating entity in EF Core application with SQLite gives DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I try to use optimistic concurrency check in EF Core with SQLite.
The simplest positive scenario (even without concurrency itself) gives me 
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded`.

Entity:

```
public class Blog
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
internal class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=D:\incoming\test.db");
        ///optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(p => p.Timestamp)
            .IsRowVersion()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
    }
}
```

Sample:

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();
            db.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Id = id, Name = "1" });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            var existing = db.Blogs.Find(id);
            existing.Name = "2";
            db.SaveChanges(); // Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException'
        }

    }
}
```

I suspect it's something to do with the data types between EF and SQLite.
Logging gives me the following query on my update:

```
Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p1='2bcc42f5-5fd9-4cd6-b0a0-d1b843022a4b' (DbType = String), @p0='2' (Size = 1), @p2='0x323031382D31302D30372030393A34393A3331' (Size = 19) (DbType = String)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
UPDATE "Blogs" SET "Name" = @p0
WHERE "Id" = @p1 AND "Timestamp" = @p2;
```

But the column types are BLOB for both Id and Timestamp (SQLite does not provide UUID and timestamp column types):

[image]

---

At the same time if I use SQL Server (use commented connection string + remove `.HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")`), sample works correctly and updates timestamp in the DB.

Used packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="2.1.4" />
```

Have I configured the model for concurrency check wrong?
That drives me crazy that I can't make it work with this simplest scenario.

---

**UPDATE:** how I finally made it work. Here only idea is shown, but probably it helps anybody:

```
public class Blog
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Version { get; set; }
}

internal class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=D:\incoming\test.db");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(p => p.Version)
            .IsConcurrencyToken();
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        long ver;
        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();
            var res = db.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Id = id, Name = "xxx", Version = DateTime.Now.Ticks});
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            var existing = db.Blogs.Find(id);
            existing.Name = "yyy";
            existing.Version = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            db.SaveChanges(); // success
        }

        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            var existing = db.Blogs.Find(id);
            existing.Name = "zzz";
            existing.Version = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            db.SaveChanges(); // success
        }

        var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var db = new Context())
            {
                var existing = db.Blogs.Find(id);
                existing.Name = "yyy";
                existing.Version = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        });

        var t2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var db = new Context())
            {
                var existing = db.Blogs.Find(id);
                existing.Name = "zzz";
                existing.Version = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        });

        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2); // one of the tasks throws DbUpdateConcurrencyException
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried only uncommenting the connection string code?

Comment: @viveknuna, if change SQLite connection string to SQLServer one, I have to remove _.HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")_ as it's illegal value for SQL Server (_Defaults cannot be created on columns of data type timestamp. Table 'Blogs', column 'Timestamp'.
Could not create constraint or index._)

Comment: Can you try “getdate()” instead of “current_timestamp”?

Comment: @viveknuna, first of all, I'm interested in solution for **SQLite**. As I stated, my sample works with SQL Server. Second: TIMESTAMP values are automatically generated and assigned by SQL Server. The specification of a DEFAULT constraint for a column of this data type is unnecessary and therefore not allowed.

Comment: I’m suggesting solution for SQLite only. Which EF Core version you have ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181423/discussion-between-flam3-and-vivek-nuna).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like EF Core SQLite provider does not handle properly `[TimeStamp]` (or `IsRowVersion()`) marked `byte[]` properties when binding them to SQL query parameters. It uses the default `byte[]` to **hex** `string` conversion which is not applicable in this case - the `byte[]` actually **is** a `string`.

First consider reporting it to their issue tracker. Then, until it gets resolved (if ever), as a workaround you can use the following custom [`ValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions):

```
class SqliteTimestampConverter : ValueConverter<byte[], string>
{
    public SqliteTimestampConverter() : base(
        v => v == null ? null : ToDb(v),
        v => v == null ? null : FromDb(v))
    { }
    static byte[] FromDb(string v) =>
        v.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray(); // Encoding.ASCII.GetString(v)
    static string ToDb(byte[] v) =>
        new string(v.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray()); // Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(v))
}
```

Unfortunately there is no way to tell EF Core to use it only for parameters, so after assigning it with `.HasConversion(new SqliteTimestampConverter())`, now the db type is considered `string`, so you need to add `.HasColumnType("BLOB")`.

The final working mapping is

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .Property(p => p.Timestamp)
        .IsRowVersion()
        .HasConversion(new SqliteTimestampConverter())
        .HasColumnType("BLOB")
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
```

You can avoid all that by adding the following custom SQLite RowVersion "convention" at the end of your `OnModelCreating`:

```
if (Database.IsSqlite())
{
    var timestampProperties = modelBuilder.Model
        .GetEntityTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
        .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(byte[])
            && p.ValueGenerated == ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate
            && p.IsConcurrencyToken);

    foreach (var property in timestampProperties)
    {
        property.SetValueConverter(new SqliteTimestampConverter());
        property.Relational().DefaultValueSql = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP";
    }
}
```

so your property configuration could be trimmed down to

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
    .Property(p => p.Timestamp)
    .IsRowVersion();
```

or totally removed and replaced with data annotation

```
public class Blog
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem was indeed in `byte[]` <--> `string` conversion.
Using `SqliteTimestampConverter` I succeeded to update entity in my sample without exception, but concurrency check didn't work anyway. I had to add trigger on entity UPDATE to refresh Timestamp value (half-manually). Also I substituted `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with `STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'NOW')` (more precision), but no luck. So I gave up and started using `long Ticks` as concurrency token (see in my initial question under cut).

Comment: @flam3 Ah, I forgot that default value applies only on insert. Whatever type you choose for the column in the database, EF will expect it to be automatically updated by the database. So I guess you would need a db trigger for updating it (not sure what type of trigger though, I'm not familiar with SQLite as a database at all)

Comment: @flam3 The triggers are described here [link](https://elanderson.net/2018/12/entity-framework-core-sqlite-concurrency-checks/)

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by this [thread on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12260) and the Ivan's answer I wrote this code to ensure on my unit testing to mimic the SQL Server concurrency.

```
var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");

var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ActiveContext>()
               .UseSqlite(connection)
               .Options;

var ctx = new ActiveContext(options);

if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    connection.Open();

    ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

    var tables = ctx.Model.GetEntityTypes();

    foreach (var table in tables)
    {
        var props = table.GetProperties()
                        .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(byte[])
                        && p.ValueGenerated == Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate
                        && p.IsConcurrencyToken);

        var tableName = table.Relational().TableName;

        foreach (var field in props)
        {
            string[] SQLs = new string[] {
                $@"CREATE TRIGGER Set{tableName}_{field.Name}OnUpdate
                AFTER UPDATE ON {tableName}
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE {tableName}
                    SET RowVersion = randomblob(8)
                    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
                END
                ",
                $@"CREATE TRIGGER Set{tableName}_{field.Name}OnInsert
                AFTER INSERT ON {tableName}
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE {tableName}
                    SET RowVersion = randomblob(8)
                    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
                END
                "
            };

            foreach (var sql in SQLs)
            {
                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = sql;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the beaty of a solution but at least the only one that worked for me

Comment: Not works for me, the rows version is updated but my properties do not change with SQLite ( my code works with SQLServer )

Comment: @OrcusZ, the problem may be that EF Core 7 uses the `RETURNING` statement to return the value of `Version`, but SQLite will only return values modified directly by the executed SQL statement. Since `AFTER UPDATE` triggers execute after the updating statement, the old `Version` value will be returned. If you change the trigger to `BEFORE UPDATE`, it should work.

Comment: @AsbjørnUlsberg Doesn't work either. While not throwing concurrency errors, it also doesn't update the rowversion either. Any way to switch to previous behavior, if to test some integration tests that tightly rely on EF Core ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use `Guid`:

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

This issue is discussed and reproduced in [Gitub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9166):

> The error here is due to ApplicationUser.ConcurrencyStamp property.
>   ApplicationUser in identity uses ConcurrencyStamp of type Guid for
>   concurrency. When creating new class it sets the value to NewGuid().
>   When you create new ApplicationUser like that and set its state to
>   Modified EF Core does not have data about what was ConcurrencyStamp in
>   database. Hence it will use whatever is the value set on the item
>   (which will be NewGuid()) Since this value differ from value in
>   database and it is used in where clause of update statement, exception
>   is thrown that 0 rows modified when expected 1.
>
> When updating entity with concurrency token you cannot create new
>   object and send update directly. You must retrieve record from
>   database (so that you have value of ConcurrencyStamp) then update the
>   record and call SaveChanges. Since the
>   ApplicationUser.ConcurrencyStamp is client side concurrency token you
>   also need to generate a NewGuid() while updating the record. So it can
>   update the value in database.

Find more info about how to deal with `ApplicationUser.ConcurrencyStamp` [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/f555a26b4a554f73eea70b4b34fca823fab9a643/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore.cs#L175).

Comment: It's property `byte[] Timestamp` which I use for concurrency, not `Guid Id`.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52738603) with great success up to this point. When I updating to EntitiyFrameworkCore 3.1, though, I started getting this warning:

> The property '{column name}' on entity type '{entity name}' is a collection or enumeration type with a value converter but with no value comparer. Set a value comparer to ensure the collection/enumeration elements are compared correctly.

To address this, I enhanced his solution by adding:

```cs
property.SetValueComparer(new ValueComparer<byte[]>(
    (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
    c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
    c => c.ToArray()));
```

(based off of [a response](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17471#issuecomment-526330450) to a GitHub issue)

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to make it work with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` because it ends up with the string displayed in both DB Browser for SQLite and EF. Having entity property of type `long` leads to the `2022` value and prevents me to save the column because obviously `2022` != `2022-12-09 14:03:14`. It also has seconds only which is bad for concurrency.

So I have decided to go with the other solution

### `byte[]` + `SetDefaultValueSql("randomblob(8)")` + update trigger

The property itself represents regular version column

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] Version { get; set; }
```

Now we need to add some reflection magic in order to assign default value on insert for all entities at once:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    var versionProperties = builder.Model
        .GetEntityTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties().Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(byte[]) && p is { ValueGenerated: ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate, IsConcurrencyToken: true }));

    foreach (var property in versionProperties)
    {
        property.SetDefaultValueSql("randomblob(8)");
    }
}
```

And the last step: we need to force DB to update the `Version` column on row update. We need a trigger for it but I didn't want any manual work in migration so here is automation based on the migration and seeding process:

```
public class AppDbContextSeedingService
{
    private readonly string VersionColumnName = nameof(EntityBase.Version);
    private readonly string IdColumnName = nameof(EntityBase.Id);
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
    public AppDbContextSeedingService(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public async Task EnsureMigratedAndSeededAsync(CancellationToken cToken = default)
    {
        await _dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync(cancellationToken: cToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var triggerNames = await _dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw<string>("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'trigger'")            .ToArrayAsync(cToken).ConfigureAwait(false);;
        foreach (var tableName in typeof(AppDbContext).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>)).Select(p => p.Name))
        {
            var updateTriggerName = GetUpdateTriggerName(tableName);
            if(triggerNames.Contains(updateTriggerName))
                continue;
            await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
                $"CREATE TRIGGER {updateTriggerName} AFTER UPDATE ON {tableName} BEGIN UPDATE {tableName} SET {VersionColumnName} = randomblob(8) WHERE {IdColumnName} = NEW.{IdColumnName}; END", cToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    private static string GetUpdateTriggerName(string tableName) => $"{tableName}_OnUpdate";
}
```

So we get the list of existing triggers then iterate through all the `DBSet<>` properties and insert missing triggers.

### But there is limitation from SQLite side.

EF Core makes this request during update:

```
UPDATE "PrinterOperations" SET "CommandJson" = @p0
WHERE "Id" = @p1 AND "Version" = @p2
RETURNING "Version";
```

So the idea is to return updated `Version` value after column update using the new `RETURNING` clause.
https://www3.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html

Unfortunately:

> The RETURNING clause only returns rows that are directly modified by the DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement. The RETURNING clause does not report any additional database changes caused by foreign key constraints or triggers.

It means that item returned after the `SaveChanges()` will have the same `Version` value as it was before because SQLite returns the old value instead of the new one. So you will not be able to change and save it again. You can easily check it with the following line:
`var sqlQueryRaw = BitConverter.ToString(dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw<byte[]>("UPDATE PrinterOperations SET CommandJson = '111111' WHERE Id = '73cf2572-4ba3-4693-922c-b062be47707c' RETURNING Version").ToArray().First());`

Just run it couple of times

Comment: You can circumvent `RETURNING "Version"` not returning the updated `Version` value by changing the SQLite database trigger from `AFTER UPDATE` to `BEFORE UPDATE`.