# Adding child within One-to-Many relationship results in exception when SaveChangesAsync() is called

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

First of all I tried finding solution for my problem here in SO and other places but none of  them could solve my issue. I made a simplified version of my problem from the production code in order to make it more understandable
I have a parent entity called `WorkEntity`. It has an one-to-one relationship with the entity called `QuotationEntity`. This `QuotationEntity` has an One-To-Many relationship with `QuotationLine.` So far so good. Let's see how the classes look like. First the `WorkEntity`:

```
public class WorkEntity : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public QuotationEntity QuotationEntity { get; set; }


    public WorkEntity()
    {
        QuotationEntity = new QuotationEntity();
    }
}
```

Then the `QuotationEntity`

```
public class QuotationEntity : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid WorkEntityId { get; set; }
    public WorkEntity WorkEntity { get; set; }

    public ICollection<QuotationLine> Lines { get; set; } = new List<QuotationLine>();
}
```

Last but not least the `QuotationLine`:

```
public class QuotationLine : Entity
{
    public string Price { get; set; }

    public Guid QuotationEntityId { get; set; }
    public QuotationEntity QuotationEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Let's see how my test code looks like and what is the occurred exception I am struggling with:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestAddingChildElement()
    {
        var repo = new WorkEntityRepository(DbContext);
        var workEntity = new WorkEntity();
        repo.Insert(workEntity);

        await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        var workFromDb = await repo.GetAsync(workEntity.Id);
        workFromDb.QuotationEntity.Lines.Add(new QuotationLine());

        await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

My test is fairly simple. First I create `WorkEntity` with its corresponding `QuotationEntity` without no `QuotationLine`. After persisting this entity, I retrieve it with the corresponding repository, then I try to add a `QuotationLine` to the `QuotationEntity`. When the `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` is invoked at the second time, I got the following exception:

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.**

The `WorkRepository` class looks like this:

```
public class WorkEntityRepository : IWorkEntityRepository
{
    private readonly DbSet<WorkEntity> _entities;
    private readonly WarehousingDbContext _dbContext;

    public WorkEntityRepository(WarehousingDbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
        }

        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _entities = dbContext.Set<WorkEntity>();
    }

    public Task<WorkEntity> GetAsync(Guid id)
    {
        return GetWorkEntityIncludingChilds().SingleAsync(p => p.Id == id);
    }


    public WorkEntity Insert(WorkEntity workEntity)
    {

        var entity = _entities.Add(workEntity);

        return entity.Entity;
    }


    private IQueryable<WorkEntity> GetWorkEntityIncludingChilds()
    {
        return _entities
            .Include(c => c.QuotationEntity)
                .ThenInclude(w => w.Lines);
    }
}
```

For configuring the One-To-One relationship between `WorkEntity` and `QuotationEntity` I use the following code snipped:

```
        builder.HasOne(a => a.QuotationEntity)
            .WithOne(b => b.WorkEntity)
            .HasForeignKey<QuotationEntity>(b => b.WorkEntityId);
```

Last but not least, I use in memory SQLite database and EF Core 3.1 for reproducing this issue:

```
    private void SetUpInMemorySqlLiteDb(ServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<WarehousingDbContext>(o => o
            .UseSqlite("Data Source=:memory:")
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
    }
```

Since I have spent much time on trying to fix the issue, I have some findings:

1. One possible reason for this exception could be that child entities are not included when the `WorkEntity` is retrieved from the repository. If I would not include them, then it would be logical that the entity is not tracked by the EF ChangeTracker. But as you can see I include all the child entities.
2. What I found out during debugging is that the `QuotationLine` has not got the correct state. If I set its state explicitly like:

   ```
       var quotationLine = new QuotationLine();
       DbContext.Entry(quotationLine).State = EntityState.Added;
       workFromDb.QuotationEntity.Lines.Add(quotationLine);
   ```

then everything works as expected. But I think it is not the solution, it is just a hacky workaround. The EFCore should handle the ChangeTracking of the element as far as I know.

Let me know then I can provide more code for my problem if needed. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: could you get rid of `public WorkEntity()` constructor and run the test again?

Comment: @kebek I did it, but unfortunately it does not solve it :( Thanks anyway for the comment!

Comment: @mirind4 JFYI was not able to repro with inmemory db. Can you try it?

Comment: @GuruStron Hey Guru! Thanks for  you comment! To be honest I want to keep using the SQLite provider, since it is what I use for testing purposes. It seems to be there is a bug in the SQLite provider side...

Comment: @mirind4 then for now you can use this hacky way. To make it less hacky you can try to do something like this: `DbContext.QuotationEntityLines.Add(new QuotationLine{QuotationEntityLinesId = workFromDb.QuotationEntity.Id})` (a lot of assumptions about names =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I think it is not the solution, it is just a hacky workaround. The EFCore should handle the ChangeTracking of the element as far as I know.

I think you should change your mind about it!

I do some research about this issue. As a result what can I say is that it could be some known bug in EF Core itself or its sqlite provider. See these tickets for more info:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9166

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9803#issuecomment-391315406

[Updating entity in EF Core application with SQLite gives DbUpdateConcurrencyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684458/updating-entity-in-ef-core-application-with-sqlite-gives-dbupdateconcurrencyexce)

Comment: The second one is fixed in EF 3.0 based on status.